# Blender select all the faces inside a loop of selected faces

Tags: python, blender, contour

Given a contour of selected faces, is there a simple way, with a python script, or some existing Blender functionality, to select all the faces that are inside the contour.

Example:

Contour selected

[image]

Filled contour:

[image]

My approach so far, since in my case all the vertices are on a sphere with a given radius, is to calculate every face's spherical coordinates to reduce the problem to 2d space, then build a polygons with vertices of contour face's spherical coordinates and then for each face in the mesh, check if their spherical coordinates are inside the polygon.

It works, but it fails miserably on poles, since for the faces there one of the coordinates(latitude or longetude) is almost the same, while the other one ranges from -180 to 180.

So is there any other, more generic approach to this problem?

Comment: Not a python script, but you can do this using the UI: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180113/how-can-i-select-all-inner-faces-of-a-current-selection-of-faces

Answer (score 1):

From the OP:

> Obviously my approach was wrong. Instead of selecting a face loop I should have selected an edge loop, and then use function "Select loop inner region" from "Edges" menu. Or using `bpy.ops.mesh.loop_to_region()` function from python.